# Discord Bot issue with command function

Tags: python, discord, bots

So I'm making a discord bot at the moment, one about fun & economy. I'm trying to make a percent command for a specific command I plan to include, but ran into these errors.

Undefined variable 'randint' (Yes I already imported random)
Missing mandatory keyword 'value' in method call (I am using value?)

```
@bot.command(name='xx', help='xx')
async def test(ctx, *args):
    value = randint(1,101)
    embed = discord.Embed(title="**Meter**")
    embed.add_field(name="User is" + value + "example")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: is this a method in a class or a function on a module? how did you import the name `randint` ?

Comment: Turns out I needed to make randint into a string variable. All fixed